# How to style span classes

Tags: css

```html
<span class="field-timer-jquery-countdown is-countdown" data-field-timer-key="node-193-field_count_down-0-_u5MJcSN8bY" data-timestamp="1606588298">
<span class="countdown-row countdown-show4">

<span class="countdown-section">
<span class="countdown-amount">2</span>
<span class="countdown-period">Days</span></span>

<span class="countdown-section"><span class="countdown-amount">17</span><span class="countdown-period">
Hours</span></span><span class="countdown-section"><span class="countdown-amount">27</span><span class="countdown-period">Minutes</span></span>
<span class="countdown-section"><span class="countdown-amount">33
</span><span class="countdown-period">Seconds</span></span></span></span>
```

I like to give fixed width and also some padding but below css does not work. It does apply background and margin just fine. [Here is my site](http://tech67.com/node/7) just incase if you would like to see. I am having issue with the countdown 2. How can I give fixed width to day, hour, min, and sec and some padding as well?

```
.countdown-section {background: #060695;margin:10px; width:100px; padding:10px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `display:inline-block` or `display:block;` to your span so that you can set it's width and height.

```css
.countdown-section {background: #060695;margin:10px; width:100px; padding:10px;display:inline-block;color:#fff;box-sizing:border-box;}
```

```html
<span class="field-timer-jquery-countdown is-countdown" data-field-timer-key="node-193-field_count_down-0-_u5MJcSN8bY" data-timestamp="1606588298">
<span class="countdown-row countdown-show4">

<span class="countdown-section">
<span class="countdown-amount">2</span>
<span class="countdown-period">Days</span></span>

<span class="countdown-section"><span class="countdown-amount">17</span><span class="countdown-period">
Hours</span></span><span class="countdown-section"><span class="countdown-amount">27</span><span class="countdown-period">Minutes</span></span>
<span class="countdown-section"><span class="countdown-amount">33
</span><span class="countdown-period">Seconds</span></span></span></span>
```

**RE-EDITED**

Add this css in your site.

```
.is-countdown span.countdown-section {display:block; width:22%; padding:20px;}
```

The parent div element is `is-countdown` class you need to specify first the parent element and then the `child div element` secondly as css are strict to specificity.

I've tested it in your site and this one is the result.

[image: Countdown Image]

Comment: I updated my site. It did not work for me. Please advise!

Comment: @KaimeiWang hi please try the `RE-EDITED` part this should work by now.